# Using the chromium-widevine Debian package

Tags: debian, chrome

As of at least Debian 9 (stretch), Debian contains the contrib package
`chromium-widevine`. The description of this package is:

> This package provides support for the widevine content decryption module.

However, after installing this package, I'm unable to find any sign that Chromium recognizes or is loading this plugin. The location of Widevine in this package is `/usr/lib/chromium/libwidevinecdmadapter.so`.

My current use for this package is to play Amazon Prime Video on Chromium.  Currently I am getting the error:

> Your web browser is missing a digital rights component. Go to chrome://components and under WidevineCdm, click Check for update.

chrome://components doesn't list WidevineCdm under Chromium.

For extra weird, I'm getting:

```
root@orwell:/usr/lib/chromium# ldd libwidevinecdmadapter.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffccbfad000)
        libwidevinecdm.so => not found
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f08c6e5b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f08c6ad3000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f08c6733000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e84bdbe000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f08c642b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f08c6213000)
```

So `libwidevinecdm.so` resolves to nothing?

Any idea what I'm supposed to do here? The `chromium-widevine` has no documentation or indication how one is supposed to proceed.

NOTE: This question is out of date, at least as of Debian 10/buster, because the chromium-widevine package no longer exists.

Comment: if there is no documentation in the package, then file a bug report stating that.    IMO that's at least an "important" (or perhaps even "grave") [severity level](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/Developer#severities) bug.

Answer (score 9):

I had no luck using netflix with `chromium-widevine` on debian 9.3 from contrib repo. What I did was:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/1.4.8.1008-linux-x64.zip
unzip 1.4.8.1008-linux-x64.zip
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/chromium
sudo mv libwidevinecdm.so /usr/lib/chromium
sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/chromium/libwidevinecdm.so
```

Comment: Just to be clear, did this recipe work for you?

Comment: yes, watching netflix on debian 9.3 on chromium right now :)

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I'll try this approach. Though I wonder why the Debian package does not work.

Comment: No idea. `ldd` gave me the same output when I was using deb package. Shared libraries look different when `so` from zip was used.

Comment: I can confirm, this works! Really simple, fast but it will be a hard to maintain solution. The Debian Project strongly recommends against doing self installs of binary blobs from the Internet especially to anywhere but /usr/local, and my experience doing so is that the package manager breaks come upgrade time. I wish Debian would offer a useful package for widevinecdm, which would save headaches. I can't really blame this solution or Debian for this. This type of stuff happens when you try to use a proprietary platform on a Free OS.

Comment: @user1509669 Someone should really follow up with Debian about this. I don't think I did. Has anyone else?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Please, flag this answer as the right one.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Someone did https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=921738

Comment: I just tried this on Mint 19.2. with Chromium 76, and didn't work alas.

Comment: This works for me (even though Widevine still doesn't get listed under `chrome://components`). For testing purposes I checked https://bitmovin.com/demos/drm and https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/

Answer (score 0):

Debian states that all packages included in the official distribution are free software, but the Widevine CDM libraries are not in this category. There is a binary blob available in the [Chrome reference build](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/reference_builds/chrome_linux64/+/master/libwidevinecdm.so) though.

Comment: It's not terribly useful including such a package with no reference how it should be used, though. I added a link `/usr/lib/chromium# ln -s /opt/google/chrome/libwidevinecdm.so .` Now Prime Video doesn't complain about "missing a digital rights component", but it doesn't work either. It gets the same error as Google Chrome itself, which is not currently working either.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Chrome is the more likely of the two to work. Do you have any idea why it might be having problems?

Comment: Hi Fox. No, I don't. It was working until recently. But I think there have been recent upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated a script found on Arch Linux to download and install widevine in chromium. You just need to update the path to the chromium install directory. Main difference is that it will also install the manifest included in the downloaded archive and this way can show the widevine version via chrome://components in chromium. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# For ARM use this instead
# https://gist.github.com/ruario/19a28d98d29d34ec9b184c42e5f8bf29

available () {
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# Make sure we have wget or curl
if available wget; then
  SILENT_DL="wget -qO-"
  LOUD_DL="wget"
elif available curl; then
  SILENT_DL="curl -s"
  LOUD_DL="curl -O"
else
  echo "Install wget or curl" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Set Output dir
#WIDEVINE_DIR="${WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR:-/opt/google/chrome}"
#WIDEVINE_DIR="${WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR:-/usr/lib/chromium}"
WIDEVINE_DIR="${WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR:-/usr/lib/chromium-browser}"

# Use the architecture of the current machine or whatever the user has set
# externally
ARCH="${ARCH:-$(uname -m)}"
case "$ARCH" in
  x86_64) WIDEVINE_ARCH="x64" 
          WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR="$WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/_platform_specific/linux_x64" ;;
    i?86) WIDEVINE_ARCH="ia32" 
          WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR="$WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/_platform_specific/linux_x86" ;;
    arm*) echo "For ARM use https://gist.github.com/ruario/19a28d98d29d34ec9b184c42e5f8bf29 instead" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
       *) echo "The architecture $ARCH is not supported." >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
esac

# Set temp dir
TMP="${TMP:-/tmp}"

# Set staging dir
STAGINGDIR="$TMP/widevine-staging"

# Work out the latest Widevine version
#WIDEVINE_VERSION="${WIDEVINE_VERSION:-$($SILENT_DL https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/current.txt)}"
WIDEVINE_VERSION="${WIDEVINE_VERSION:-$($SILENT_DL https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/versions.txt | tail -n1)}"
echo latest Version: $WIDEVINE_VERSION

# Error out if $CDMVERISON is unset, e.g. because previous command failed
if [ -z "$WIDEVINE_VERSION" ]; then
  echo "Could not work out the latest version; exiting" >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Find current installed version
INSTALLED_VERSION=$(grep '"version":' $WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json|cut -f4 -d'"')

# Don't start repackaging if the same version is already installed
if [ $WIDEVINE_VERSION = $INSTALLED_VERSION ]; then
  echo "The latest Widevine ($WIDEVINE_VERSION) is already installed"
  exit 0
fi

# If the staging directory is already present from the past, clear it down and
# re-create it.
if [ -d "$STAGINGDIR" ]; then
  rm -fr "$STAGINGDIR"
fi

# Stop on any error
set -eu

# Make and switch to the staging directory
mkdir -p "$STAGINGDIR"
cd "$STAGINGDIR"

# Now get the latest widevine zip for the users architecture
$LOUD_DL "https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip"

# Extract the contents of Widevine package
if available unzip; then
  unzip "${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip" libwidevinecdm.so
  unzip "${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip" manifest.json 
elif available bsdtar; then
  bsdtar xf "${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip" libwidevinecdm.so
  bsdtar xf "${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip" manifest.json
else
  # The user's system has no obvious handler for Zip files. GZip can extract
  # the first entry from a Zip. If libwidevinecdm.so is the first entry, we
  # might just pull this off! ;)
  missing_extractor_error () {
    echo "Install InfoZip Unzip or BSD tar" >&2
    exit 1
  }
  # Look in first 50 bytes for libwidevinecdm.so as it'll be mentioned there
  # if it is the first entry in the zip
  if head -c50 "${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip" | grep -Fq libwidevinecdm.so; then
    # Hide the warning about multiple entries and ensure an exit code of 0
    gzip -d < "${WIDEVINE_VERSION}-linux-${WIDEVINE_ARCH}.zip" > libwidevinecdm.so 2> /dev/null ||:
    # Check that it looks like an executable
    if ! file libwidevinecdm.so | grep -Fq ELF; then
      missing_extractor_error
    fi
  else
    missing_extractor_error
  fi
fi

# Add version number file
#touch "widevine-$WIDEVINE_VERSION"
#SED_PAR="s/\"version\": \".*\"/\"version\": \"$WIDEVINE_VERSION\"/"
#if [ -e $WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json ]; then
#  sed $WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json -e "$SED_PAR" >$STAGINGDIR/manifest.json
#fi

# Escalate privileges if needed and copy files into place
#SED_PAR="s/\"version\": \".*\"/\"version\": \"$WIDEVINE_VERSION\"/"
if [ "$USER" = "root" ]; then
  install -Dm644 libwidevinecdm.so "$WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR/libwidevinecdm.so"
  if [ -e $STAGINGDIR/manifest.json ]; then
#     mv $WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest_neu.json $WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json
     install -Dm644 manifest.json "$WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json"
  fi
elif [ -r /etc/os-release ] && grep -qxE 'ID=((ubuntu)|(debiiian))' /etc/os-release; then
  echo "Calling sudo ... If prompted, please enter your password so Widevine can be copied into place"
  sudo  install -Dm644 libwidevinecdm.so "$WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR/libwidevinecdm.so"
  if [ -e "$WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR/libwidevinecdm.so" ]; then
    if [ -e $STAGINGDIR/manifest.json ]; then
      sudo install -Dm644 manifest.json "$WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json"
    fi
  else
    echo "Something went wrong installing libwidevinecdm.so" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
else
  echo "Please enter your root password so Widevine can be copied into place"
  su -c "sh -c \"install -Dm644 libwidevinecdm.so $WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR/libwidevinecdm.so && install -Dm644 manifest.json $WIDEVINE_DIR/WidevineCdm/manifest.json\""
fi

# Tell the user we are done
echo "Widevine ($WIDEVINE_VERSION) installed into $WIDEVINE_INSTALL_DIR/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find a chromium-widevine Debian package, I used the alternative method "Install Widevine alone without Google Chrome" mentioned at https://github.com/proprietary/chromium-widevine?tab=readme-ov-file#alternative-install-widevine-alone-without-google-chrome.

You can use the script from GitHub, which will check the latest Widevine version at https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/versions.txt and download one (based on your architecture x64 or x32) like https://dl.google.com/widevine-cdm/4.10.2710.0-linux-x64.zip before creating this directory structure in your Chromium folder (it starts with /usr/lib/chromium/ on Debian but it can change depending on your Linux distribution):

```
  /usr/lib/chromium/WidevineCdm
  ├── LICENSE
  ├── manifest.json
  └── _platform_specific
      └── linux_x64
            └── libwidevinecdm.so
```

The script also adds permissions 755 to folders and 644 to files.